# How to add two UIButtons in Tableview section header

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewsectionheader

I added custom tableview header with two buttons, but buttons are disabled , unable to make control events. i want to get layout like this. i'm new to development. any suggestions or solution 
 [image: i want selectAll/Cancel and Send buttons in Tableview section header]

i tried to add view with buttons inside view in ViewforHeaderSection function

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

```
    let inviteSectionHeaderview  = UIView.init(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height))
    let selectAllBtn = UIButton.init(frame:CGRect(x:16, y: inviteSectionHeaderview.bounds.height/2, width:130, height:20))
    let sendButton = UIButton.init(frame:CGRect(x:inviteSectionHeaderview.bounds.width - 30, y: inviteSectionHeaderview.bounds.height/2, width:60, height:20))
    selectAllBtn.setTitle("select all/Cancel", for: .normal)
    selectAllBtn.backgroundColor = .black
    sendButton.backgroundColor = .black
    sendButton.setTitle("SEND", for: .normal)
    self.contactsTable.addSubview(inviteSectionHeaderview)
    inviteSectionHeaderview.addSubview(selectAllBtn)
    inviteSectionHeaderview.addSubview(sendButton)
    return inviteSectionHeaderview

}
```

[image: by implementing above code i'm getting like this]

Comment: can you add code on what have you tried so far .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Create your `UIView` in storyboard
2. Create programatically

**Option 2**

1. Create your `UIView`.

   ```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? 
       let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 30.0))        

       // Button1
       let button1 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 15.0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 28.0)
       button1.setTitle("Button 1", for: .normal)
       button1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(selectorButton1), for: .touchUpInside)

       // Button2
       let button2 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: tableView.frame.width-150, y: 0, width: 150, height: 30.0))
       button2.setTitle("Button2", for: .normal)
       button2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(selectorButton2), for: .touchUpInside)
       button2.semanticContentAttribute = UIApplication.shared
           .userInterfaceLayoutDirection == .rightToLeft ? .forceLeftToRight : .forceRightToLeft

       headerView.addSubview(button1)
       headerView.addSubview(button2)
       return headerView 
   }


       @objc func selectorButton1(_ sender : Any) {

       }

       @objc func selectorButton2(_ sender : Any) {

       }
   ```

In this case, you must set correctely `y` and `x` positions when create `UIView(frame: CGRect())` and `UIButton(frame: CGRect())`

**EDIT**

From your code, you just need add the targets:

```
selectAllBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(selectorAllBtn), for: .touchUpInside)
sendButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(selectorSendButton), for: .touchUpInside)

@objc func selectorAllBtn(_ sender : Any) {

}

@objc func selectorSendButton(_ sender : Any) {

}
```

Comment: yeah, i did like that and i added two buttons in that view. those are not getting click events.

Comment: I will try your code @Augusto and give you feedback ASAP

Comment: I've edited t you put in your code, just copy and paste.

Comment: Solution with the storyboard would be more robust, just creating the whole header view only once and reusing it time to time. Auto layout would come in rescue while dealing with calculating frames.

Comment: @RatulSharker I agree with you, But in this case to do more easy from code that's user already wrote.

Comment: Works fine @Augusto . and add right brace to button1 CGrect line. Thanks!

Comment: button2.semanticContentAttribute = UIApplication.shared
        .userInterfaceLayoutDirection == .rightToLeft ? .forceLeftToRight : .forceRightToLeft what is the use of this code. could you explain @Augusto

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        var headerView = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "headerView")

        if headerView == nil {
            headerView = UITableViewHeaderFooterView(reuseIdentifier: "headerView")

            let button1 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 8, y: 8, width: 80, height: 40))
            button1.setTitle("Select", for: .normal)
            button1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
            headerView?.addSubview(button1)

        }

        return headerView
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 50 // set a height for header view
    }

    @objc func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
     // write your code...
    }
```