# (Automatic) reloadData on Tableview(tabbar2) once Array is updated in tabbar1 (without needing to change tabbars)

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-bluetooth

tabbar1 - I'm using core-bluetooth to connect to some peripherals. Once it connects, I update an array.

```
 func populateFoundBTArray(peripheral: CBPeripheral, service:CBService) {
     discoveredBTDevices.append(BTPeripheral.init(
                               id: discoveredBTDevices.count, 
                               name: peripheral.name!, 
                               uuid: peripheral.identifier, 
                               desc: service.uuid.description
                               connected: peripheral.state == .connected ? true : false ))
    }
```

in TabBar2 - I have some prototype (custom) cells hooked up via a XIB file via a combo of Static Cells and dynamic cells (similar to this solution - https://stackoverflow.com/a/49157374/14414215)

within TabBar2 - I have the `tableView.reloadData()` call which is great whereby, whenever I switch to this tabbar2, the tableview will get updated. (but I have to physically go to tabbar1 --> tabbar2 to trigger this update)

```
  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    tableView.reloadData()
  }
```

my goal Is would like to be able to get the tableview to reload whenever the array `discoveredBTDevices` gets updated.

I did try

```
let pop = tabbar2()
pop.tableView.reloadData() // also tried reloadSections(1 but didn't work
```

along with some more answers I found on SO but none of them worked. (I did not try any segues / notifications as currently I just have the discoveredBTDevices as a global variable to simplify my initial test)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting my own answer as to how I solved this issue of mine. It is not a full solution but rather a workaround but I believe that it is suitable.

From the original post, the goal is to get the tableviewcell to refresh once the array `discoveredBTDevices` gets updated. To Recap, currently the table will only refresh once the user switch to tabbar1 and then back to tabbar2 (due to the `reloadData()` called in `viewDidAppear`)

After searching and reading through 40+ SO pages on `UITableview` and not finding an answer, I decided to utilise a UIButton to do manual table reload.

```
  // https://stackoverflow.com/a/53032365/14414215
  //
  // https://stackoverflow.com/a/44735567/14414215
  //
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    if section == deviceSection { // this is my paired device section of the static table
      let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 30.0))
      
      let sectionHeader = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 8, y: 0, width: 200, height: 30.0))
      sectionHeader.text = "PAIRED BLUETOOTH DEVICES"
      sectionHeader.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
      sectionHeader.textColor = UIColor.systemGray
      
      let reloadButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: tableView.frame.width-150, y: 0, width: 150, height: 30.0))
      reloadButton.setTitle("Reload", for: .normal)
      reloadButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ReloadButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
      reloadButton.semanticContentAttribute = UIApplication.shared
          .userInterfaceLayoutDirection == .rightToLeft ? .forceLeftToRight : .forceRightToLeft

      headerView.addSubview(reloadButton)
      headerView.addSubview(sectionHeader)
      return headerView
    }
    return super.tableView(tableView, viewForHeaderInSection: section)
  }


  @objc func ReloadButtonTapped(_ sender : Any) {
    tableView.reloadData()
  }
```

I have linked 2 SO pages which shows the implementation and merged it slightly as using `viewForHeaderInSection` will remove all stylings from using Apple's native header hence the addition of the `sectionHeader`